# Allow xml:space="preserve" in XSD for validation

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an xml file with a schema i wrote but its failing with the line:

```
Element 'Route', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}space': The attribute '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}space' is not allowed.
```

the XML file sometimes contains this:

```
 <Route xml:space="preserve">

</Route>
```

which is obviously causing the problem, what can i do to my xsd file to allow for this?

Here is my XSD with everything non relevant removed

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet">
      <xs:element name="Route" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="FurtherRequirements" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
```

etc. etc.

All help gratefully received!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change `Route` from being of type `xs:string` to being of type `string-with-xml-space`, where `string-with-xml-space` is a complex type with simple content, defined something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="string-with-xml-space">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute ref="xml:space"/>
```

You will also need an `xs:import` of the schema for the XML namespace:

```
<xs:import namespace='http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'  
           schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd'/>
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by 
"You will also need an xs:import of the schema for the XML namespace.".. treat me like an idiot here please

Comment: If you reference definitions in another namespace (like xml:space) then you need to import the schema for that namespace. This applies to the xml namespace just like any other. The schema for the xml namespace is at http://www.w3.org/2004/10/xml.xsd